# What is the difference between the `--build` and `--force-recreate` flags to `docker-compose up`?

Tags: docker-compose

Just as the title asks; what is the difference between the `--build` and `--force-recreate` flags to `docker-compose up`?

To me it seem that these would do the same thing, but maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As mentioned in a [doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/), or the help of docker-compose up,

`--build`: build images before starting containers.

`--force-recreate`: Recreate containers even if their configuration and image haven't changed.

`--build` is a straightforward and it will create the docker images before starting the containers. The `--force-recreate` flag will stop the currently running containers forcefully and spin up all the containers again even if you do not have changed anything into it's configuration. So, if there are any changes, those will be picked-up into the newly created containers while preserving the state of volumes. The counter to this is `--no-recreate` to keep the containers in their existing state and it will not consider the respective changes into the configuration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation.  This makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Vorticity: glad you like it and understood. Thanks for accepting.

Comment: Looks like `--no-recreate` is the default behavior and as such can be omitted.

Comment: What is the use-case for `--force-recreate`?

Comment: @k0pernikus when the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` itself MODIFIES the container, `--build` won't recreate the container, which means the second run is on the dirty container. Use `--force-recreate` to run on a clean container.

Comment: What is CMD and ENTRYPOINT and what does it mean to modify the container?

Answer (score 4):

`--build:` - rebuilds images(not containers - as `--force-recreate` does) according to the newest changes, normally it does not automatically update/builds them

`--force-recreate:` - recreates containers meaning that things like commands  history is preserved, also some installed utilities, due to that, of course, the previous containers must be stopped and therefore is many times "incorrectly" misused as a shortcut for stopping and starting=restarting containers with a single command for instance when one makes runtime-affecting capable changes, eg as php values configurations by environmental variables and wants to see them immediately, fastly, etc

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docker compose's document it will automatically find any changes in the docker-compose.yml file (image or configuration part of a service) and recreate related containers but it will not realize any changes in the dockerfile:

> If there are existing containers for a service, and the service’s
> configuration or image was changed after the container’s creation,
> docker compose up picks up the changes by stopping and recreating the
> containers (preserving mounted volumes). To prevent Compose from
> picking up changes, use the --no-recreate flag.

So for `docker compose up` the `--no-recreate` is not a default option.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/

But regardless of not having any changes if you want to have fresh containers you can use `--force-recreate`:

> If you want to force Compose to stop and recreate all containers, use
> the --force-recreate flag.

So for rebuilding images after having changes in the dockerfile you still need to run with `--build`.

Note that using `--build` alone will not create fresh containers based on the new build images so you need to run with `--force-recreate` .

(As said it will only recognize changes in the docker-compose.yml file (image or configuration part of a serevice) and your change is in the dockerfile so `--force-recreate` is required with `--build` if you don't have a change in docker-compose.yml as well)