# docker-compose random i/o timeout with --force-recreate

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple Issue with Docker-compose, But Its a random issue.

I have a `docker-compose.YAML` for spring services, When I update the service and want to check the update, I build a new image to docker daemon with `google jib`, and I use `docker-compose up --force-recreate` to get the new updates.

The issue is, most of the time with `--force-recreate` I will have an error `ERROR: for serviceName b'i/o timeout'`

So I `docker-compose down`  Then `docker-compose up --build` which will have the same effect

as `docker-compose up --force-recreate` according to my simple understanding of docker, but when I do this down up, I have no issue, Any idea what might be the issue for this case?

Comment: What is the environment you are working in? Is it Docker on Windows by any chance?

Comment: Yes, Its docker for windows

Comment: For explanation of the difference between `--build` and `--force-recreate` check [this thread][1]. It does not explain the timeouts, however. [On this GitHub issue][2], it is suggested to run the docker commands (or Docker Desktop) as administrator. For me personally, Docker timeouts every now and then and I need to restart the service, reinstalls and other tricks do not help. You can try also disabling WSL 2.0.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52106464/what-is-the-difference-between-the-build-and-force-recreate-flags-to-do
  [2]: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4413